# What is the difference between androidx.collection.ArrayMap vs android.util.ArrayMap?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I already looked at the source code, the only thing i'm curious about to know why both the versions are exist one should had to be deprecated, no ?

Today I was writing unit tests for one of my viewModel class, in the repository class I have used `android.util.ArrayMap`. I did initialize ArrayMap with fake value but while debugging found that arrayMap size is always zero.

```
 arrayMap["key1"] = someValue
 arrayMap["key2"] = someValue
 arrayMap["key3"] = someValue
```

But when I change it to `androidx.collection.ArrayMap` it works fine. But the problem is I already used `android.util.ArrayMap` in my repository and viewModel class and at this moment I don't want to convert that to `androidx.collection.ArrayMap`.

Here is the test class.

```
import android.util.ArrayMap
//import androidx.collection.ArrayMap // switching to this works fine
import org.junit.*
import org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
class AudioViewModelTest {

    private lateinit var audioMap: ArrayMap<Int, AudioItem>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        audioMap = ArrayMap()
        val audioItem = AudioItem()
        audioMap[1] = audioItem
        audioMap[2] = audioItem
        audioMap[3] = audioItem
        assertNotNull(audioMap[1])// this is failing
    }

    @Test
    fun testAudioMap() {
       assertNotNull(audioMap[1])// this is failing
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain why `android.util.ArrayMap` always have size as ZERO even if I add some element into that.

Comment: post your whole testing code, not three lines

Comment: Yes, I did. Results are same.

Comment: Is it an instrumented test?

Comment: @AndreiTanana, No. It's a local. If possible for you guys can try the same piece of code at your end

Comment: Are you sure `AudioItem()` doesn't return null ?

Comment: What's the output of `size()` or `isEmpty()` just to be sure?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Android platform classes in your local tests. In your local test, you have just mock of the `android.util.ArrayMap` class. That's why it's size is always 0. You have to use instrumented tests or use `androidx.collection.ArrayMap`